# Use of Django-tables2 for table display on template

Tags: python-3.x, django-tables2

Can anyone give me the required steps to implement the django-tables2 package in django 1.11?
I want to convert a simple table into the django-tables format.

Comment: And what you tried till now?

Comment: I have tried using simple HTML Tables <tr><th></th></tr> format in index.html template file. Values in this field were coming from views.py file. I just wanted to convert this simple HTML table format in to django-tables2 format. I have already installed it on my offline machine. But I am not knowing the steps and how to use it.

Comment: Always update question, with informations like that.

Comment: Did you look at the django-tables2 tutorial? http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html